# multiline checkbox using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to add some more text with a different style and in yellow.

Is there a way to do this inside checkbox?

for example:

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-6b" id="checkbox-v-6b">
     <label for="checkbox-v-6b">some text</label>
</fieldset>
```

I've tried to add another label but that didn't work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsbin.com/oXan/1/)? Not sure what you are trying to do, if you want to change the color you can use a theme swatch `data-theme="e"`, as for more text why don't you use the same label?

Comment: i want to do something like this http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-nested.html  only with a checkBox